# Return Largest Numbers in ArraysPassed using reduce method

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is a question in freecodecamp which is as follows:

> Return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided sub-array. For simplicity, the provided array will contain exactly 4 sub-arrays.
>
> Remember, you can iterate through an array with a simple for loop, and access each member with array syntax arr[i].
>
> Thus largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
>
> should return [ 5, 27, 39, 1001 ].

There are numerous methods to do the above map() method being the shortest. However I am trying to achieve the same using reduce method but unable to do that. My method is as follows.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((maxArray,item) => maxArray.push(Math.max(...item)),[]); 
}
```

But there is error in console which says

```
maxArray.push is not a function
```

Kindly find the bug.

Comment: maxArray.push(Math.max(...item) doen't return an array, so, in the second iteration maxArray is not an Array

Comment: There is no need to use `Array.reduce()`, you can use `Array.map()` on the external array and the spread operator (`...`) on the internal arrays with `Math.max()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.push(...)` returns the new `length` of the array, not the array itself, so at the second loop, you're pushing to a number, instead of the array, hence you need to change your arrow function:

```
const largestOfFour = arr => arr.reduce(
  (max, current) => (max.push(Math.max(...current)), max),
  []
);
```

That would work.

Comment: Thanx.. for the solution. Got the mistake...I was returning max.push(..) instead of max in the reducer function.